# To what domains does Iyachtu Xvim grant access?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

The feat [**Godsblood Spelltheft**](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111223109/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frcc/20070606) has as its benefit the ability to select a domain granted by [Iyachtu Xvim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iyachtu_Xvim), the Baneson who assumed his father's hatred and tyranny portfolios for about a decade until he became the vessel for his father's return.

#### Is there an official list of domains available to clerics of Iyachtu Xvim?

In *Monsters of Faerûn* (Feb. 2001) Xvim is alive, but he's toast by the *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* (June 2001), and, afterward, he's barely a footnote. Both texts are from the *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* era, but information from the *3.5* era is fine, especially considering the publication date of the Class Chronicles Web column "Factotums and Spellthieves" (June 2007).

Official treeware and Web sources are acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Into the Dragon's Lair*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786916346) (Oct. 2000)—the first long-form *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* adventure published for the Forgotten Realms and that was published *before* the [*Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786918365) (May 2001)—includes in its appendix a section entitled Pantheon Conversion. The subsection Sample Conversions includes the first look at how the deities Chauntea, Cyric, Lathander, Tempus, Tymora, and Tyr could be translated from [adnd-2e](/questions/tagged/adnd-2e) to [dnd-3e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3e). Later texts would describe in much greater detail these deities for [dnd-3e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3e) and [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e).

However, the subsection Sample Conversions is *also* the sole source that I can find of the following information:

> **Iyachtu Xvim**—*Domains:* [Destruction](http://dndsrd.net/clericDomains.html#destruction), [Evil](http://dndsrd.net/clericDomains.html#evil-domain), [Law](http://dndsrd.net/clericDomains.html#law-domain), [Strength](http://dndsrd.net/clericDomains.html#strength-domain). *Favored Weapon:* scimitar. (96)

(Links mine.) While only a *sample* conversion and not a thorough and complete update of the soon-to-be-dead god's place in a long-term campaign, it remains the only mention I've found of what domains the god *could* have. Interestingly, the Baneson's domains include the domain Strength, to which [Bane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Forgotten_Realms_deities#Greater_deities) himself doesn't typically grant access. This domain list is otherwise unexceptional, doing nothing, for example, [to expand the utility](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93640/8610) of the feat [Godsbood Spelltheft](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111223109/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frcc/20070606).

Answer (score 11):

The two most thorough compendiums of deity and domain information are [imarvintpa’s Deity Search](https://www.imarvintpa.com/dndlive/FindDeity.php) and [Curmudgeon’s Cleric Domain List](https://web.archive.org/web/20151026092248/http://home.comcast.net:80/%7Eftm3/ASMoNM/domains.html). Neither lists anything with “xv” or “iya.” This **strongly** suggests that the god is never defined in 3rd edition, as both sources are **extremely** comprehensive.

On the off-chance that either had skipped web material, I also checked a Google search of

> site:archive.wizards.com "iyachtu xvim"

This resulted in only three hits: the Class Chronicles article you already mentioned, this [*Monsters of Faerûn* web enhancement](https://web.archive.org/web/20200105203623/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20010216a), which only mentions him in relation to some monster in that book (tyrantfog), and a Magic Books of Faerûn article, [“Kaupaer’s Quick Book (Spells for the Hastiest Mage)”](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101073517/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mb/20050112a), which mentions that Teresken, the last known bearer of *Kaupaer’s reflexive strike*, “was disappointed with Iyachtu Xvim's attempts to claim Bane's legacy.” So neither of those help.

A search for just “xvim” reveals little more: a “beast of Xvim,” a passing mention of a “Fzoul” who became “Chosen of Xvim (and then Chosen of Bane),” the bearer of a cursed dagger being driven mad and running straight into a fight between Cyric and Xvim, a web enhancement promising that *Cloak and Dagger* (a 2nd-edition book) included a full description of Fzoul’s becoming the Chosen of Xvim, and that’s it.

And a search for just “iyachtu” revealed that the term is never used except in the phrase “iyachtu xvim.”

So, being out of any kind of official rules behind this, I tried the lore. Iyachtu Xvim was Bane’s son, and kind of proxy god while Bane was dead, used to revive Bane. Fzoul, who *Monsters of Faerûn* claims is the “Chosen of Iyachtu Xvim,” is nonetheless still listed as a cleric of Bane in *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting*. According to the novels, he was a cleric of Bane, and then (insincerely) of Cyric, and then of Iyachtu Xvim, and then of Bane once again. It is possible that *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* and *Monsters of Faerûn* are just referring to him at different times, but considering Iyachtu Xvim’s close association with Bane and Bane’s divinity, it’s possible that he was simply carrying on for Bane during the Time of Troubles. So he may have simply offered Bane’s domains (Destruction, Envy, Evil, Hatred, Law, Pride, Tyranny, Wrath).

I also spoke with afroakuma, noted expert on D&D lore. His suggestions for Iyachtu Xvim’s domains were Evil, Hatred, Law, Strength, maybe Domination and/or Suffering too. Hatred would have been the important one.

Notably, of these options, only Domination would introduce a new option to Godsblood Spelltheft, and that was one of the weakest suggestions, so maybe it doesn’t really matter.

Comment: Although fun to read, neither of the fan sites is complete, omitting as they do, for example, *Lost Empires of Faerûn* Ancient Deities (41-3). They are, however, pretty darn useful.

Comment: I should clarify: Neither of those fan sites mentions a few of the other deities also on the Godsblood Spelltheft list that are given an official list of domains elsewhere. (That is, *incomplete* in this case means the sites omit the *domains of dead gods*, which is, I admit, a pretty high bar to set for incomplete, but necessary in this case.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ah, excellent point; unfortunately, I’m out

Comment: @HeyICanChan Well, an update of sorts, though it doesn’t fully answer the question.