# What domains are eligible to be chosen for the Godsblood Spelltheft feat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, religions-and-deities, domains

The [Godsblood Spelltheft](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frcc/20070606) feat says, in part, to

> Select a domain from one of the deities involved in the Time of Troubles on the following list:
>
> Anhur, Bane, Bhaal, Clangeddin Silverbeard, Gilgeam, Gond, Gwaeron Windstrom, Hoar, Ibrandul, Iyachtu Xvim, Kelemvor, Labelas Enoreth, Leira, Malar, Mask, Myrkul, Mystra, Nobanion, Ramman, Red Knight, Selune, Shar, Shaundakul, Tiamat, Torm, Tymora

The problem is, finding these deities and their associated domains is quite difficult.

What is the full, complete, and comprehensive list of domains associated with these deities from any official Wizards of the Coast 3.*x*e supplement or official magazine covering 3.*x*e (i.e. certain issues of *Dragon* or *Dungeon*)?

Comment: Related: [To what domains does Iyachtu Xvim grant access?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70044)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Godsblood Spelltheft](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frcc/20070606) domains and their associated deities

The feat Godsblood Spelltheft allows picking one domain associated with any of the deities involved in the [Time of Troubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_Troubles_(Forgotten_Realms)). That's a lot of deities, and a lot of domains spread out over numerous sources. Below is the list I've compiled.

The Domain column lists the clerical domain and, parenthetically, the domain's textual location. The Deity or Deities column lists the deity associated with the domain and, parenthetically, where that deity is said to grant access to that domain. Official Wizards of the Coast initialisms are used, and a list of those is available as part of this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610). The answer's writer apologizes for not making this table friendlier, but it was running a little long already.

\begin{array}{l|l}
\text{Domain} & \text{Deity or Deities} \\ \hline
\text{Air (PH 185)} & \text{Gilgeam (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Shaundakul (FRCS 250, FP 222, PG 84)} \\ \hline
\text{Avarice (Dragon #323 63)} & \text{Hoar (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Mask (Dragon #323 65)} \\ \hline
\text{Animal (PH 186)} & \text{Gwaeron Windstrom (FRCS 234, FP 222,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 84)} \\
 & \text{Malar (FRCS 245, FP 222, PG 84)} \\
 & \text{Nobanion (FRCS 234, FP 222, PG 84)} \\ \hline
\text{Bestial (BV 80)} & \text{Malar (PG 189)} \\ \hline
\text{Cavern (SpC 271)} & \text{Ibrandul (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Shar (FRCS 249, FP 222, PG 85)} \\ \hline
\text{Chaos (PH 186)} & \text{Anhur (FRCS 236, FP 141, PG 85)} \\
 & \text{Labelas Enoreth (FRCS 238, FP 128,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 85)} \\
 & \text{Malar (FRCS 245, FP 222, PG 85)} \\
 & \text{Sel}\hat{\text{u}}\text{ne (FRCS 248, FP 222, PG 85)} \\
 & \text{Shaundakul (FRCS 250, FP 222, PG 85)} \\
 & \text{Tymora (FRCS 253, FP 222, PG 85)} \\ \hline
\text{Charm (SpC 271)} & \text{Leira (LE 141)} \\ \hline
\text{Chastity (Dragon #355 25-6)} & \text{Sel}\hat{\text{u}}\text{ne (Dragon #355 26)} \\ \hline
\text{City (RD 162, 163)} & \text{Gond (RD 162)} \\
 & \text{Mask (RD 162)} \\ \hline
\text{Craft (SpC 272)} & \text{Gond (FRCS 241, FP 222, PG 85)} \\ \hline
\text{Darkness (SpC 272) [see below]} & \text{Ibrandul (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Mask (FRCS 246, FP 222, PG 189,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 85)} \\
 & \text{Shar (FRCS 249, FP 222,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 85 and 189)} \\ \hline
\text{Death (PH 186)} & \text{Bhaal (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Kelemvor (FRCS 243, FP 222)} \\
 & \text{Myrkul (LE 141)} \\ \hline
\text{Destruction (PH 185)} & \text{Bane (FRCS 237, FP 222, PG 86)} \\
 & \text{Bhaal (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Tiamat (CD 117, DD 93, Dr 35, RDr 149)} \\ \hline
\text{Dragon (SpC 273)} & \text{Tiamat (Dr 35, RDr 149)} \\ \hline
\text{Dwarf (SpC 273)} & \text{Clangeddin Silverbeard (FRCS 238, FP 116)} \\ \hline
\text{Earth (PH 186)} & \text{Gond (FRCS 241, FP 222, PG 86)} \\ \hline
\text{Elf (SpC 273)} & \text{Labelas Enoreth (FRCS 238, FP 128)} \\ \hline
\text{Envy (SpC 273-4)} & \text{Bane (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Hoar (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Mask (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Shar (Dragon #323 65)} \\ \hline
\text{Evil (PH 186)} & \text{Bane (FRCS 237, FP 222, PG 86)} \\
 & \text{Bhaal (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Malar (FRCS 245, FP 222, PG 86)} \\
 & \text{Mask (FRCS 246, FP 222, PG 86)} \\
 & \text{Myrkul (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Shar (FRCS 249, FP 222, PG 86)} \\
 & \text{Tiamat (FRCS 234, CD 117, DD 93, DF 94,} \\
 & \quad\text{Dr 35, RDr 149, PG 86)} \\ \hline
\text{Fate (SpC 274)} & \text{Hoar (FRCS 241, FP 222, PG 86)} \\
 & \text{Kelemvor (FRCS 243, FP 222, PG 84 and 86)} \\ \hline
\text{Fey (BE 86)} & \text{Nobanion (PG 189)} \\ \hline
\text{Fire (PH 187)} & \text{Gond (FRCS 241, FP 222, PG 87)} \\ \hline
\text{Generosity (Dragon #355 26-27)} & \text{Tymora (Dragon #355 26)} \\ \hline
\text{Gluttony (SpC 274)} & \text{Malar (Dragon #323 65)} \\ \hline
\text{Good (PH 187)} & \text{Anhur (FRCS 236, FP 141, PG 87)} \\
 & \text{Clangeddin Silverbeard (FRCS 238, FP 116,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 87)} \\
 & \text{Gwaeron Windstrom (FRCS 241, FP 222,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 87)} \\
 & \text{Labelas Enoreth (FRCS 238, FP 128, PG 87)} \\
 & \text{Mystra (FRCS 247, FP 222, PG 87)} \\
 & \text{Nobanion (FRCS 234, FP 222, PG 87)} \\
 & \text{Sel}\hat{\text{u}}\text{ne (FRCS 248, FP 222, PG 87)} \\
 & \text{Torm (FRCS 253, FP 222, PG 87)} \\
 & \text{Tymora (FRCS 253, FP 222, PG 87)} \\ \hline
\text{Greed (SpC 275)} & \text{Tiamat (PG 189, Dr 35, RDr 149)} \\ \hline
\text{Hatred (SpC 275)} & \text{Bane (FRCS 237, FP 222, PG 87)} \\
 & \text{Tiamat (Dr 35, RDr 149)} \\ \hline
\text{Healing (PH 187)} & \text{Torm (FRCS 253, FP 222)} \\ \hline
\text{Hunt (Dragon #342 89)} & \text{Malar (Dragon #342 89)} \\ \hline
\text{Illusion (SpC 275)} & \text{Leira (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Mystra (FRCS 247, FP 222, PG 87)} \\ \hline
\text{Knowledge (PH 187)} & \text{Gond (FRCS 241, FP 222, PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Gwaeron Windstrom (FRCS 241, FP 222,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Labelas Enoreth (FRCS 238, FP 128, PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Mystra (FRCS 247, FP 222, PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Shar (FRCS 249, FP 222, PG 88)} \\ \hline
\text{Law (PH 187)} & \text{Bane (FRCS 237, FP 222, PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Clangeddin Silverbeard (FRCS 238, FP 116,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Hoar (FRCS 241, FP 222, PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Kelemvor (FRCS 243, FP 222, PG 84 and 88)} \\
 & \text{Nobanion (FRCS 234, FP 222, PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Ramman (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Red Knight (FRCS 234, FP 222, PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Tiamat (FRCS 234, CD 117, DD 93, DF 94,} \\
 & \quad\text{Dr 35, PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Torm (FRCS 253, FP 222, PG 88)} \\ \hline
\text{Luck (PH 187)} & \text{Mask (FRCS 246, FP 222, PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Tymora (FRCS 253, FP 222, PG 88)} \\ \hline
\text{Magic (PH 188)} & \text{Mystra (FRCS 247, FP 222, PG 88)} \\ \hline
\text{Metal (SpC 276)} & \text{Gond (FRCS 241, FP 222, PG 88)} \\ \hline
\text{Moon (SpC 277)} & \text{Malar (FRCS 245, FP 222, PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Sel}\hat{\text{u}}\text{ne (FRCS 248, FP 222, PG 88)} \\ \hline
\text{Night (Dragon #342 89)} & \text{Sel}\hat{\text{u}}\text{ne (Dragon #342 89)} \\
 & \text{Shar (Dragon #342 89)} \\ \hline
\text{Nobility (SpC 277)} & \text{Nobanion (FRCS 234, FP 222, PG 88)} \\
 & \text{Red Knight (FRCS 234, FP 222, PG 88)} \\ \hline
\text{Patience (Dragon #355 28-29)} & \text{Labelas Enoreth (Dragon #355 26)} \\ \hline
\text{Planning (SpC 278)} & \text{Gond (FRCS 241, FP 222, PG 89)} \\
 & \text{Ramman (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Red Knight (FRCS 234, FP 222, PG 89)} \\ \hline
\text{Plant (PH 188)} & \text{Gwaeron Windstrom (FRCS 241, FP 222,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 89)} \\ \hline
\text{Portal (SpC 278)} & \text{Shaundakul (FRCS 250, FP 222, PG 89)} \\ \hline
\text{Pride (SpC 278-9)} & \text{Bane (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Gond (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Nobanion (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Shar (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Torm (Dragon #323 65)} \\ \hline
\text{Protection (PH 188)} & \text{Kelemvor (FRCS 243, FP 222, PG 84 and 89)} \\
 & \text{Ramman (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Sel}\hat{\text{u}}\text{ne (FRCS 248, FP 222, PG 89)} \\
 & \text{Shaundakul (FRCS 250, FP 222, PG 90)} \\
 & \text{Torm (FRCS 253, FP 222, PG 90)} \\
 & \text{Tymora (FRCS 253, FP 222, PG 90)} \\ \hline
\text{Repose (PG 90)} & \text{Kelemvor (PG 84 and 90)} \\ \hline
\text{Retribution (SpC 279)} & \text{Bhaal (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Hoar (FRCS 241, FP 222, PG 90)} \\ \hline
\text{Rune (SpC 279)} & \text{Mystra (FRCS 247, FP 222, PG 90)} \\ \hline
\text{Scalykind (SpC 279)} & \text{Ibrandul (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Tiamat (FRCS 234, Dr 35, RDr 149)} \\ \hline
\text{Sloth (SpC 280)} & \text{Mask (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Tymora (Dragon #323 65)} \\ \hline
\text{Spell (SpC 280)} & \text{Leira (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Mystra (FRCS 247, FP 222, PG 91)} \\ \hline
\text{Storm (SpC 280)} & \text{Anhur (FRCS 236, FP 141, PG 92)} \\ \hline
\text{Strength (PH 188)} & \text{Anhur (FRCS 236, FP 141, PG 92)} \\
 & \text{Clangeddin Silverbeard (FRCS 238, FP 116,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 92)} \\
 & \text{Gilgeam (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Malar (FRCS 245, FP 222, PG 92)} \\
 & \text{Torm (FRCS 253, FP 222, PG 92)} \\ \hline
\text{Suffering (SpC 280-1)} & \text{Myrkul (LE 141)} \\ \hline
\text{Temperence (Dragon #355 29-30)} & \text{Clangeddin Silverbeard (Dragon #355 26)} \\
 & \text{Red Knight (Dragon #355 26)} \\ \hline
\text{Time (SpC 281)} & \text{Labelas Enoreth (FRCS 238, FP 128)} \\ \hline
\text{Trade (SpC 281)} & \text{Shaundakul (FRCS 250, FP 222, PG 92)} \\ \hline
\text{Travel (PH 188)} & \text{Gwaeron Windstrom (FRCS 241, FP 222,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 92)} \\
 & \text{Hoar (FRCS 241, FP 222, PG 92)} \\
 & \text{Ibrandul (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Kelemvor (FRCS 243, FP 222, PG 84 and 92)} \\
 & \text{Sel}\hat{\text{u}}\text{ne (FRCS 248, FP 222, PG 92)} \\
 & \text{Shaundakul (FRCS 250, FP 222, PG 92)} \\
 & \text{Tymora (FRCS 253, FP 222, PG 92)} \\ \hline
\text{Trickery (PH 188)} & \text{Leira (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Mask (FRCS 246, FP 222, PG 92)} \\
 & \text{Tiamat (CD 117, DD 93, Dr 35, RDr 149)} \\ \hline
\text{Tyranny (SpC 281)} & \text{Bane (FRCS 237, FP 222, PG 92)} \\
 & \text{Gilgeam (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Tiamat (FRCS 234, Dr 35, RDr 149, PG 92)} \\ \hline
\text{Undeath (SpC 281)} & \text{Myrkul (LE 141)} \\ \hline
\text{War (PH 188)} & \text{Anhur (FRCS 236, FP 141, PG 92)} \\
 & \text{Clangeddin Silverbeard (FRCS 238, FP 116,} \\
 & \quad\text{PG 92)} \\
 & \text{Gilgeam (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Ramman (LE 141)} \\
 & \text{Red Knight (FRCS 234, FP 222, PG 92)} \\ \hline
\text{Wrath (SpC 282)} & \text{Anhur (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Bane (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Clangeddin Silverbeard (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Hoar (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Malar (Dragon #323 65)} \\
 & \text{Tiamat (Dragon #323 65)} \\ \hline
\text{Zeal (Dragon #355 30)} & \text{Torm (Dragon #355 26)} \\
\end{array}

And, because it was handy, below are the gods by pantheon.

\begin{array}{l|l}
\text{Pantheon} & \text{Gods} \\ \hline
\text{Dwarven} & \text{Clangeddin Silverbeard} \\
\text{Faer}\hat{\text{u}}\text{nian} & \text{Bane, Bhaal [dead], Gond, Gwaeron Windstrom, Hoar,} \\
 & \quad\text{Ibrandul [dead], Kelemvor, Leira [dead], Malar, Mask,} \\
 & \quad\text{Myrkul, Mystra, Nobanion, Red Knight, Sel}\hat{\text{u}}\text{ne, Shar,} \\
 & \quad\text{Shaundakul, Tiamat, Torm, Tymora} \\
\text{Mulhorandi} & \text{Anhur} \\
\text{Untheric} & \text{Gilgeam [dead], Ramman [dead]} \\
\end{array}

Ask the DM if the *Lords of Madness* domain Vile Darkness (208)—a specific revision of the *Book of Vile Darkness*'s domain Darkness (85)—can be picked instead of the *Spell Compendium* domain Darkness. The *Player's Guide to Faerûn* allows a creature to pick either the *Book* domain or one like the one in the *Compendium* (189), yet the *Guide* predates the *Compendium*. [The situation's kind of a mess](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93658/8610).

Although listed among the deities whose domains can be chosen, [Iyachtu Xvim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_deities_in_Dungeons_%26_Dragons#Iyachtu_Xvim) [hasn’t been given an official list of domains to which his clerics have access](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70044/8610). *Monsters of Faerûn* (Feb. 2001) discusses the god as if he were alive but by the *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* (June 2001) he's dead and often less than a footnote in later texts, despite the June 2007 publication date of ["Factotums and Spellthieves."](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frcc/20070606)

While the [Tiamat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiamat_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) mentioned in some sources is *not* the *same* [Tiamat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiamat_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Forgotten_Realms) as the Forgotten Realms deity, *all* sources mentioning Tiamat have been included for completeness. Domain overlap between these same-named deities means the only *real* decision a DM must make is whether the Forgotten Realms deity Tiamat can grant a creature with the feat Godsblood Spelltheft access to the domain Dragon.

I have only a passing familiarity with *Dungeons and Dragons, Fourth Edition* but, apparently, that edition adds domains to some of the listed gods (e.g. the domain Creation to Gond, the domain Shadow to Shar). While these domains have names lining up with *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* domains (e.g. the *Spell Compendium* includes the domain Creation (272) and the *Eberron Campaign Setting* presents the domain Shadow (108)), these domains are assumed to be different mechanically from their *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* counterparts and omitted from the list above.

(*Trivia:* The only *Player's Handbook* domains *not* represented above are Sun and Water.)

Answer (score 0):

Searching each of these deities on [imarvintpa](http://www.imarvintpa.com/dndlive/FindDeity.php) and eliminating duplicates yields this list:

> Air, Animal, Avarice, Bestial, Cavern, Chaos, City, Darkness, Destruction, Dragon, Dwarf, Earth, Elf, Envy, Evil, Fate, Fey, Fire, Gluttony, Good, Greed, Hatred, Healing, Illusion, Knowledge, Law, Luck, Magic, Metal, Moon, Nobility, Planning, Plant, Portal, Pride, Protection, Repose, Retribution, Rune, Scalykind, Sloth, Spell, Storm, Strength, Time, Trade, Travel, Trickery, Tyranny, Vile Darkness, War, Wrath

Notably, however, imarvintpa has no entry for Bhaal, Gilgeam, Ibrandul, Iyachtu Xvim, Leira, Myrkul, or Ramman. The only other thorough listing of domains I know, [Curmudgeon’s](http://ftm3.altervista.org/ASMoNM/domains.html), doesn’t have them either. Indeed, we have an [existing question about Iyachtu Xvim](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70044/4563) where I determine that, to the extent of the resources available to me can reveal, he was never statted for 3.5e. HeyICanChan does suggest that *Lost Empires of Faerûn* has stats for dead gods that are not found at either of those resources, so I will check that for these gods when I get a chance.